# Unknown type name 'AClass' in objective c

Tags: objective-c

In my MyClass.h, I have this:

```
#import "AClass.h"

@interface MyInterface  : UIViewController  <UIScrollViewDelegate>    
@property (strong, nonatomic) AClass *ptr;
@end
```

But when I compile it, I get an error saying Unknown type name 'AClass' , did you mean 'BClass'.

What I don't understand it I already have "#import "AClass.h", how can I fix my error?

In AClass.h, I have

```
@interface AClass : UICollectionViewFlowLayout

@end
```

And both AClass.h and MyClass.h are in the same directory.

Thank you.

Comment: Make sure MyClass exist

Comment: There's a couple things I see that are wrong here. First is that I'm not sure how you're getting past your `@interface` line - this should cause an error due to lack of a superclass. While this isn't the source of your problem, it's considered bad form to import a header file in another header file unless it's your superclass's header - use the `@class` directive instead.

Comment: Is AClass.h importing MyClass.h also? then you should use @class in case of bidirectional referencing

Comment: No. AClass.h does not import MyClass.h. Do I need to export the interface AClass in AClass.h or something? I don't understand why MyClass.h can't see it.

Answer (score 0):

(This answer is obsolete since the question was changed including the displayed code)

It's your headerfile, right? So don't import yourself.

In MyClass.m you need *#import "MyClass.h"*, but not in the header file of MyClass itself.